# Count the spaces at start of a string

Tags: c#, string, count, whitespace

How would I count the amount of spaces at the start of a string in C#?

example:

```
"    this is a string"
```

and the result would be 4. Not sure how to do this correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use `Enumerable.TakeWhile`, `Char.IsWhiteSpace` and `Enumerable.Count`

```
int count = str.TakeWhile(Char.IsWhiteSpace).Count();
```

Note that not only `" "` is a white-space [but](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

White space characters are the following Unicode characters:

- Members of the SpaceSeparator category, which includes the characters SPACE (U+0020), OGHAM SPACE MARK (U+1680), MONGOLIAN VOWEL SEPARATOR (U+180E), EN QUAD (U+2000), EM QUAD (U+2001), EN SPACE (U+2002), EM SPACE (U+2003), THREE-PER-EM SPACE (U+2004), FOUR-PER-EM SPACE (U+2005), SIX-PER-EM SPACE (U+2006), FIGURE SPACE (U+2007), PUNCTUATION SPACE (U+2008), THIN SPACE (U+2009), HAIR SPACE (U+200A), NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE (U+202F), MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE (U+205F), and IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE (U+3000).
- Members of the LineSeparator category, which consists solely of the LINE SEPARATOR character (U+2028).
- Members of the ParagraphSeparator category, which consists solely of the PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR character (U+2029). The characters CHARACTER TABULATION (U+0009), LINE FEED (U+000A), LINE TABULATION (U+000B), FORM FEED (U+000C), CARRIAGE RETURN (U+000D), NEXT LINE (U+0085), and NO-BREAK SPACE (U+00A0).

.... so basically spaces, new-lines- and tabs

Comment: Just what I needed, thanks! and thanks for the information on white spaces.

Answer (score 11):

You can use LINQ, because `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>`:

```
var numberOfSpaces = input.TakeWhile(c => c == ' ').Count();
```

Answer (score 10):

```
input.TakeWhile(c => c == ' ').Count()
```

Or

```
input.Length - input.TrimStart(' ').Length
```

Comment: The `TrimStart` solution is the simplest.

Comment: @helrich well, it produces new string, so it's not best option for long strings :) Thus I posted two solutions

Comment: Both do slightly different things since `TrimStart` internally uses `Char.IsWhiteSpace`. Check it on `input=" \t text"`. First returns 1 and the second 3 since the tab-character is counted as white-space.

Comment: The second line should be `input.Length - input.TrimStart(' ').Length` to have the same result as the first one.

Comment: @helrich: a subtraction of two different values where i need to think about the order is not simpler than `TakeWhile(Char.IsWhiteSpace).Count()` (once you understand that a string is an `IEnumerable<char>`)

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks Tim, didn't know that `TrimStart` treats `\t` and `\r` as white-spaces

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string s = "    this is a string";
            Console.WriteLine(count(s));
        }

        static int count(string s)
        {
            int total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                if (s[i] == ' ')
                    total++;
                else
                    break;
            }
            return total;
        }
```

Comment: Wow, that's really a lot of code when you compare this to the LINQ equivalent in MarcinJuraszek's answer. I don't miss these awful days when we had no LINQ. :)

Comment: Assuming you want to avoid LINQ and use raw C#, Changing that `for` to a `while` loop would be much shorter

Answer (score -1):

While I like the Linq based answers here's a boring unsafe method that should be pretty fast

```
    private static unsafe int HowManyLeadingSpaces(string input)
    {
        if (input == null)
            return 0;
        if (input.Length == 0)
            return 0;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            return input.Length;

        int count = 0;
        fixed (char* unsafeChar = input)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                if (char.IsWhiteSpace((char)(*(unsafeChar + i))))
                    count++;
                else
                    break;
            }
        }

        return count;           


    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 int count = 0, index = 0, lastIndex = 0;
  string s = "    this is a string";

  index = s.IndexOf(" ");
  while (index > -1) 
  {
    count++;
    index = s.IndexOf(" ", index + 1);

    if ((index - lastIndex) > 1)
      break;

    lastIndex = index;
  } 

  Console.WriteLine(count);
```