# Count the number of whitespaces at the beginng of the string

Tags: vb.net, string, whitespace

Is there an easy way using vb.net to count whitespaces in at the beginning of the string?

For example my string is "   this is a test". The number of whitespaces in the beginning is 3. Is there a built-in function to count them programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count the spaces at start of a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411812/count-the-spaces-at-start-of-a-string)

Comment: `input.Length - input.TrimStart(' ').Length`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trim the leading white space and compare lengths:

```
num = s.Length - LTrim(s).Length
```

Or find the first non-whitespace character an check its index:

```
Dim match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(s, "\S")
If match.Success Then
    num = match.Index
End If
```

Comment: I'd prefer to recommend `s.TrimStart` rather than `LTrim` :)

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works well in VB.Net and has the advantage that it is so short that it does not disturb the flow of your method.   Despite using a loop to do the counting, the timing tests provided in this [C# post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695501/get-index-of-first-non-whitespace-character-in-c-sharp-string) suggest that a Loop is surprisingly efficient.  My application does not warrant doing the timing tests for this use of Linq functionality in VB.Net - perhaps someone else's does and they could comment here?  Credits to [@Henk Holtermann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman).

```
Dim WhiteSpaceCount As Integer  'The number of white spaces at the start
WhiteSpaceCount  = MyString.TakeWhile(Function(C As Char) Char.IsWhiteSpace(C)).Count
```